# is it possible that No one can scan my QR code

Tags: qr-code

I am developing a QR code application. But I am interested that no one can scan my QR code except my application? Is it possible or not?

Comment: Yes, Its possible. For example imagine you just change some random squares that only your application knows about.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. but can you refer me to some kind of link that how I can change some random squares in image?

Comment: How about just encrypt the data and use a regular QR code? Your question is very general so i can only give a general answer. Pls try something first.

Comment: THANKYOU for encryption standard suggestion. I will consider this technique.